How to install Tor browser on 20.04, when 404 error code results
Greetings and thank you in advance. I have used Firefox to download the Tor browser and attempted to install it resulting in error code 404.
I followed the instructions from this website:https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/01/install-tor-tor-browser-ubuntu-20-10-20-04/
I have also looked up the error regarding installing Tor, on Firefox and followed the advice regarding how to work around the error. All to no avail.
I am stuck. I am working with a new laptop, I uninstalled Windows on and installed Ubuntu in its place.
Here are the specs: Dell Inc. Precision 7520 32.0 GiB Mem. Intel® Core™ i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz × 8  NV126 / Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)  512.1 GB HD  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
64-bit  Wayland  Jammy Jellyfish
-------------If the accepted answer to the duplicate question didn't work for you please comment and request me to reopen your question and I will reopen it. –
karel
Please reopen it karel.
I read both posts and answers on marked identical questions and was not able to get different results, using methods given. There is so much information that I struggle to make sense of. I expect my problem is that I am ignorant of what is being discussed and how to identify the relevant solutions and implement them. Tried entering text into terminal that was suggested. Repeated the process from the beginning. Same result.
As below:
ruby-sdbm - simple file-based key-value store with String keys and values
rust-1.62-all - Rust systems programming language - all developer tools
rust-1.62-clippy - Rust linter
rust-1.62-gdb - Rust debugger (gdb)
rust-1.62-lldb - Rust debugger (lldb)
rust-1.62-src - Rust systems programming language - source code
rustc-1.62 - Rust systems programming language
rustfmt-1.62 - Rust formatting helper
xe-guest-utilities - daemon for monitoring Xen Virtual machines
libnvidia-nscq-535 - NVSwitch Configuration and Query library
libnvidia-nscq-550 - NVSwitch Configuration and Query library
nala - Commandline frontend for the APT package manager
docker-registry - Docker toolset to pack, ship, store, and deliver content
etcd-client - highly-available key value store -- client
etcd-server - highly-available key value store -- daemon
golang-etcd-server-dev - highly-available key value store -- source
golang-github-docker-distribution-dev - Docker toolset to pack, ship, store, and deliver content (source)
monit - utility for monitoring and managing daemons or similar programs
N: Ignoring file 'tor-project.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

...ruby-sdbm - simple file-based key-value store with String keys and values
rust-1.62-all - Rust systems programming language - all developer tools
rust-1.62-clippy - Rust linter
rust-1.62-gdb - Rust debugger (gdb)
rust-1.62-lldb - Rust debugger (lldb)
rust-1.62-src - Rust systems programming language - source code
rustc-1.62 - Rust systems programming language
rustfmt-1.62 - Rust formatting helper
xe-guest-utilities - daemon for monitoring Xen Virtual machines
libnvidia-nscq-535 - NVSwitch Configuration and Query library
libnvidia-nscq-550 - NVSwitch Configuration and Query library
nala - Commandline frontend for the APT package manager
docker-registry - Docker toolset to pack, ship, store, and deliver content
etcd-client - highly-available key value store -- client
etcd-server - highly-available key value store -- daemon
golang-etcd-server-dev - highly-available key value store -- source
golang-github-docker-distribution-dev - Docker toolset to pack, ship, store, and deliver content (source)
monit - utility for monitoring and managing daemons or similar programs
N: Ignoring file 'tor-project.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
Why not search the available packages with apt-cache search tor, pick packages to sudo apt install? –
waltinator

Why not search the available packages with apt-cache search tor, pick packages to sudo apt install?

If the accepted answer to the duplicate question didn't work for you please comment and request me to reopen your question and I will reopen it.

Note. Command line manipulation over linux is newish to me. I have repeatedly tried downloading and installing, as per instructions, and can not get tor to open. I click on the start tor browser icon and get the "Download error 404".  I have little idea what all these files are and how to understand what I'm messing up. I am used to Windows files.

apt-cache search tor results in:          N: Ignoring file 'tor-project.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension  Same with sudo apt install
